# What is the official name of this site (meta)?

Tags: discussion

The other sites official names are:
Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User.

**Update 2**: the [official name is Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19609/meta-html-title), despite the consensus here of Meta StackOverflow - this is directly from Jeff Atwood. MSO is the abbreviation.

---

Which of the following is this site's official name?

- Meta
- meta
- Meta Stack Overflow
- Meta StackOverflow
- meta StackOverflow
- meta Stack Overflow
- meta stack overflow

What is the corresponding official abbrevation (SO, SF and 
SU for the others):

- mSO
- metaSO
- MSO
- MEta
- MS

Comment: Why the downvote ? Hmm, reading the FAQ, I understand, questions here should be only about SO, SF, or SU. This one is about another site than these 3, so it should be closed... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meta (HTML) title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19609/meta-html-title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official name of this site is **Meta Stack Overflow**, like it says in the `title` of every page.

Comment: Correct. See also Jeff's answer at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19609/meta-html-title/19611#19611

Answer (score 7):

The site's official name is Awesome.

The "outside world name" is Meta StackOverflow or MSO. But, I'm partial to Awesome.

Comment: I hate you!!! Not even 1 sec difference and then you dare edit the same time as me. I WANT MY WAFFLES BACK! :)

Comment: "My name is Diago. You have taken my waffles. Prepare to die."

Comment: Now imagine Liam Neeson saying that and you have a blockbuster movie.

Comment: @Diago: Gir, is that you?

Comment: Eric, I have upvoted this. Do not even think about editing it!

Comment: @belgeriontheking: Huh or my all time favorite WTF?

Comment: @Diago: I don't get your reference.  I was refering to Gir from the TV show Invader Zim in the episode Zim Eats Waffles http://www.tv.com/invader-zim/zim-eats-waffles/episode/143598/summary.html http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1iy46_zimeatswaffles_fun

Comment: @belgeriontheking - Ahh. My brain finally woke up!

Answer (score 5):

Official Name: **Meta StackOverflow** or **Meta-StackOverflow**

Unofficial Name: **The only place TheTXI has a shot at beating Jon Skeet and Jeff Atwood at anything other than a pizza eating contest**

Abbreviation(s): **Meta** or **MSO** or **Meta SO**

Comment: I would destroy you in a pizza eating contest.

Comment: Pizza? I thought waffles? You always puzzle me. Go on!

Comment: Pizza     waffles.

Comment: I want to see that contest: Eric against the pony eating Pizza-Waffles. Who is betting?

Comment: @John: I don't *only* eat waffles. After all, pizza is sort of amazing, too.

Comment: Eric, we are talking about the combination. You get both. All for free, Diago is paying!

Comment: Hmmm..... I think the pony has a better change... But then Eric has been known to pull of some very sneaky maneuvers.

Comment: Hell yes. Let's do it.

Comment: Oi - What gives anyone the idea that I can afford it at the current exchange rate. If someone is willing to pick up the Fedex charges though, I could get the Pizza's for free :)

Comment: Exchange rate: how many waffles do I get for one pizza?

Comment: http://www.google.com.ar/search?q=1+pizza+in+waffles mmm... appearently Google does not have that exchange, but I found recipe for Waffle Pizza :D

Answer (score 1):

Meta StackOverflow - MSO.

It can however also be knows as **HE WHO SHALL NOT BE NAMED**'s personal hideout, or any other [insert funky name here] option you choose.

It makes no difference really as Jeff already said [Meta is Murder](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001282.html)

Comment: Did you notice that this is actually the "offline" logo of mso? Not the error-page, but the full "down" logo.

Comment: This is the assassins' guild!

Comment: **The Lunatics Have Taken Over the Asylum** is a proper description, IMO.

Comment: You only can take over something if you kill someone. Join the club, Treb!

Comment: I did not approve the use of my name here.

Comment: Awww Rich - It was a compliment. That downvote really hurt my feelings. I worked so hard to be a part of the club :(