# Meta (HTML) title?

Tags: bug, status-declined

Referring to the consensus in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17660/what-is-the-official-name-of-this-site-meta) the (HTML) title of this site should be:

"Meta StackOverflow" and not "Meta Stack Overflow" (?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Incorrect, it is:

> Meta Stack Overflow
>   http://meta.stackoverflow.com

and SO is:

> Stack Overflow
>   http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Also "Super User" and "Server Fault" right?

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up. I have updated http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17660