# Site/blog name clash?

Tags: discussion

Are blog / site names trademarked?

Here is [another blog](http://www.embeddedgurus.net/stack-overflow/) named Stack Overflow... What are the legal implications?

Comment: that one is 'stack-overflow' or 'Stack Overflow' (with a space), this is 'stackoverflow.' its a fine line...

Comment: That blog was started back in 2006. Apparently. At least from what the archives tell.

Comment: @akf: no, they are exactly same (despite the logo). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19609/meta-html-title/19611#19611 The official names are: Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User and Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No legal implications whatsoever - this programmer started his blog in 2006, two years before Jeff and Joel chose to name their project StackOverflow.

If anything, HE might be feeling a tad miffed.

Answer (score 3):

From that blog ([entry on June 2007](http://embeddedgurus.net/stack-overflow/2007/06/understanding-stack-overflow.html)):

> Well, it turns out that many of the visitors to this blog get here not because of the brilliance of my writing, but because they did a Google search on "stack overflow" often qualified by PIC, or MSP430 etc.

I wonder how that has changed over the last year!

Comment: That's hilarious!

Comment: Also, it looks like a pretty good blog if you're into embedded stuff.

Comment: Into having stuff embedded where, exactly?

Comment: That would be embedd*ing*.